# Unknown Process sustse/kworkerds running on servers

Tags: linux, malware, malware-removal, malware-detection

We have noticed Unknown Process sustse/kworkerds running on CoreOS servers this was identified as Cripto malware,

Followed below article but not helpfull, killed process and deleted the file in temp, after sometime again it is starting. Crontab is not running

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-is-this-sustes-in-my-process-in-my-cpu-stats

Answer (score 0):

Use `systemctl status <pid>` to determine which systemd unit contains the process. From that, you can determine the autostart method – e.g. if it's under cron.service it's obviously started by a cron job; if it's under apache2.service it's started through an infected webapp; and so on.

Answer (score -1):

There are sophisticated malwares that act as miners. Kworkerds is it one of those. Even it modify libc.so specifically readdir function. Also it is resilient to reboots and deletes. So it is not trivial remove it. Read carefully so you can be sure it is absolutely removed. Ah! note that it also remove others miners! very clever, in that way it can access more cpu resources and killing others miners will not alert incautious sysadmins.

Ref.: https://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/linux-coin-miner-copied-scripts-from-korkerds-removes-all-other-malware-and-miners/ https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-cryptocurrency-miners-are-installing-rootkits-to-hide-themselves/ https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/news/cybercrime-and-digital-threats/cryptocurrency-mining-malware-targets-linux-systems-uses-rootkit-for-stealth

Comment: This is an interesting post, but let me comment just about its quality as an answer.  The post and its linked blogs describe how this malware works, but not how to get rid of it and solve the problem.  So as-is, it isn't a solution to the question, making it more of a comment than an answer.  Consider expanding it to include that facet.